# Merging Two Arrays in to a single grouped array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've two dynamic arrays very basic format, each contain related information one another but the output fo the array is separately

```
First array are "id's"
Array
(
    [0] => 190
    [1] => 189
)
Second array are "quantities"
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 5
)
```

**The final step is to build those two arrays in to this array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [id] => 190
        [qu] => 3
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
        [id] => 189
        [qu] => 5
        )
)
```

The API I'm using has 2 outputs/files for different purposes on the first output are ID's  and second Output are "quantities"(I have no idea why they do it like that)... but the thing is that now I have the arrays I need to put them together like that...
using array_merge(); only makes a single array in list which is not working for what I need...
This is what merge those

```
Array
(
    [0] => 190
    [1] => 189
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 5
)
```

that is not going to fly...

So how can I build that array?
 Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the keys in the two arrays are identical;

```
$arr = array();
$ids = array('189', '190');
$quantities = array('3', '5');

foreach ($ids as $key => $id) {
    $arr[$key] = array('id' => $id, 'qu' => $quantities[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $id = array(
        "190",
        "189",
    );
    $quantities = array(
        "3",
        "5",
    );
    $finished = array();
    foreach($id as $key=>$item) {
        array_push($finished, array($item, $quantities[$key]));
    }

    print_r($finished);
```

Comment: Sorry I saw Pankretes's answer first, yours are working, but a +1 is yours... thank you.